# Is the equation identifiable?

Tags: regression, self-study, identifiability

Is the following equation identified. Is it possible to obtain the estimates of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in OLS estimation.

$y_t=\alpha+\beta x_t +\frac{z_t}{\beta}+u_t. $

$x_t, y_t, z_t$ are observed.

Comment: Can you observe $(x_t, z_t, y_t)$?

Comment: Yes, they are observed.

Comment: I am not sure how you would estimate a nonlinear model with OLS, although this isn't directly related to identifiability.

Comment: When all the $z_t=0$, it's an OLS regression, which is known to be identifiable.  Therefore, except possibly for very special values of the data (which is always a potential problem, even in OLS), the parameters are identifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert in identifiability, but I would say yes. Roughly speaking, you have more predictors than independent parameters. More precisely: it's unclear to me whether you are modeling a time series (because of the $_t$ suffix) or you are performing regression on a random sample (because you mention OLS). I'll go with the latter: I think the answer would be the same with the former, but I'm not sure.

Assume $u_t$ is a Gaussian zero mean error term, uncorrelated with the vector $\mathbf{x_t}=(x_t, z_t)$. Then for $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)\neq(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$, the two models

$y_t=\alpha_i+\beta_i x_t + \frac{z_t}{\beta_i}+u_t=\alpha_i+\beta_i x_t + \gamma_i z_t+u_t,\quad  i=1,2$

correspond to different distributions for $y_t$. Thus in principle the model is identifiable. In practice, since it's a nonlinear model, of course you can't use OLS to estimate it. Also, if you use any NLS method, I think you'll run into trouble unless you can put a lower bound on the absolute value of $\beta$, i.e., unless your NLS estimation algorithm can handle the nonlinear constraint $|\hat{\beta}|>\epsilon$. Here I'm assuming you're not modeling a time series: if you are, then OLS wouldn't make sense even if the model were linear, since errors are now autocorrelated. For now, I don't know enough about time series models to help you out there.

Comment: (1) What does the subscript "$i$" on the parameters indicate?  (2) In what sense is this regression problem related to time series models?  (3) You *can* solve it using a simple variant OLS, because the constraint $\beta\gamma=1$ is bilinear.  Use a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: (1) two possible sets of values for the parameters. Either $(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ or $(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$, i.e., $(\alpha_i, \beta_i), \quad i=1,2$. (2) I have no idea, if you read my answer again you can see that I was asking the OP whether the $_t$ suffix actually had some meaning, as if the data were from a time series, or if the data were just a random sample ${(\mathbf{x}_{tj},y_{tj})}$, in which case the $_t$ suffix is quite useless. (3) interesting suggestion but my knowledge of constrained least squares regression stops at linearly constrained LS, i.e., quadratic programming. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] if there's a way to solve an LS estimation problem with bilinear constraints, using standard OLS algorithms, then this sounds extremely interesting, why don't you elaborate on that? On the other hand, if solving LS with bilinear constraints requires significant programming, then personally I'd stick to NLS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from book "Econometric Theory and Methods", Russell Davidson, 2009. It is numbered 6.7. I found the answer, so I decided to post it.

$y_t=\alpha+\beta x_t +\frac{z_t}{\beta}+u_t, $
then if we define $\frac{1}{\beta}=\delta$, we would have the following
$y_t=\alpha+\beta x_t +\delta z_t+u_t$.
The above equation is identified, but keep in mind that we have nonlinear restriction $\delta=\frac{1}{\beta}$, so we can not perform OLS estimation.

Comment: what would be the difference with my answer?